# Get row when value is higher than a given row value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm trying to figure out something that's a bit hard to explain.

I have a dataframe that looks like this ([link to csv](https://pastebin.com/raw/kaQnDpe2))

```
time  value  is_critical
0:00    1      false
0:01    9      true
0:02    2      false
0:03    4      false
0:04    6      true
0:05    5      false
0:06    1      false
0:07    4      false
0:08    8      true
0:09    7      false
0:10    10     false
```

And I want to compute another dataframe with all the critical values and the date of when the value returned or surpassed the critical value. So the new dataframe would look something like this:

```
time  value  return_to_critical
0:01    9          0:10
0:04    6          0:08
0:08    8          0:10
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: This https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions/ might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit messy, and not very efficient but here's a solution:

```py
In [3]: df[df["is_critical"]].apply(lambda critical_row: df["time"][(df["time"] > critical_row["time"]) & (df["value"] >= critical_row["value"])].min(), axis=1)
Out[3]:
1    0:10
4    0:08
8    0:10
dtype: object
```

Works by first filtering out any non-critical rows, then applying a boolean expression to each row of that result: "values in the dataframe where the value is greater than or equal to the current value, and the time is greater than the current time" where "current" refers to each row in the filtered data.

You can clean up a little:

```py
def time_of_return_to_critical(df, critical_row):
    mask = (df.time > critical_row.time) & (df.value >= critical_row.value)
    return df["time"][mask].min()


df[df.is_critical].apply(lambda row: time_of_return_to_critical(df, row), axis=1)
```

Note that the `.min()` is a brittle solution. You should convert the `"time"` column to a proper datetime or timestamp data type because right now it's only "working" as a string comparator.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I can convert the time to a timestamp. I'm worried for the efficiency of this solution. My background is C++ and having to go through all the dataframe just to get the next time where we return to the value seems wrong to me. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this...

Comment: I mean, how else would you do it? Each individual critical value requires its own mask. For each critical value, you have to create a mask for rows greater than or equal to that critical value. If the critical values were all the same this would be a lot more efficient, but I can't think of another way to dynamically create boolean masks for each critical value.

Comment: Depending on your data there might be some benefit in filtering on time first and then separately filtering on the value, but I'm not super sure on that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will mark it as the solution. Since the rows are sorted I just had to get the first element after applying the mask, I did it with `return next(iter(df.loc[mask, 'time']), 'NaN')`. I also read that using `loc` is preferred over `df[mask]`, so also changed that. And I start by getting the critical slice: `critical = df.loc[df["is_critical"], ['time', 'value']]` and then I do `critical['return_to_critical'] = critical.apply(lambda row: time_of_return_to_critical(df, row), axis=1)` to get the dataframe I wanted